# Test for item in output slot of furnace

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When i put this command in a command block:

```
/testforblock ~ ~1 ~-3 minecraft:furnace 0 {Items:[{id:"minecraft:iron",Slot:1b}]}
```

It gave this error:

```
The block at 137,85,401 is Furnace (expected: Furnace).
```

And when i put this in the command block:

```
/testforblock ~ ~1 ~-3 minecraft:furnace {Items:[{id:"minecraft:iron",Slot:1b}]}
```

It gave this error:

```
'{Items:[{id:"minecraft:iron",Slot:1b}]}' is not a valid number
```

I'm trying to test for an iron ingot in the output slot. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of furnaces:

1. `furnace` (furnace turned off)
2. `lit_furnace` (Furnace when burning something)

The data Value has to be -1 or the actual rotation of the furnace (-1 means it does not matter).

So change your command to:

```
/testforblock x y z minecraft:lit_furnace -1
```

The output slot is `2b` and iron is called `iron_ingot`:

```
/testforblock x y z minecraft:furnace -1 {Items:[{Slot:2b,id:"minecraft:iron_ingot"}]}
/testforblock x y z minecraft:lit_furnace -1 {Items:[{Slot:2b,id:"minecraft:iron_ingot"}]}
```

You would have to test if one of these testfors was successful (basically do your redstone 2 times, one for each command).

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Furnace).

Comment: You can use a data value of `-1` to match all possble data values.

Comment: Thats nice, didn't now that

Comment: Thx for the edit